# Convert between different rating systems

Tags: rating, tournament

Is there a table somewhere that shows how to convert between all the various rating systems?

US Chess seems to indicate that ratings would be converted from others to play in their tournaments.

Comment: Bear in mind that since the FIDE and USCF player pools are different, and I cam sure the tournament rules and the specifics of the rating calculations are different, there is no mathematical comparison.  People kinda of guess by subtracting 100 from USCF ratings to make them on par with FIDE ratings.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're interested in conversions involving USCF ratings. [Here](http://glicko.net/ratings/rating.system.pdf) you can see the algorithm used.

As an example the conversion between FIDE and USCF is USCF = 180 + 0.94*FIDE if the FIDE rating is under 2000 and USCF = 20 + 1.02*FIDE if the FIDE rating is over 2000 elo points.

Answer (score 2):

The official conversion rate for ECF to FIDE is FIDE=7.5*ECF+700, see

http://www.englishchess.org.uk/fide-elo-conversion/

Again comments about this being approximate are appropriate.

I don't know of a more general table.

Answer (score 1):

This tool converts between USCF and FIDE ratings:

http://beginchess.com/2017/03/04/chess-rating-conversion-tool/